# NVD3 line chart - legend text cut off

Tags: d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm pretty new to D3 and NVD3. I'm playing with the line chart example which works great except for one thing: it cuts of the legend text as shown in the screen shot below. In the picture, it says "Mean Size Distributi..." instead for writing out Distribution.

Going through the [source for NVD3s legend module](https://github.com/novus/nvd3/blob/master/src/models/legend.js), I can't seem to find a setter for the legend width. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

```
chart.legend.maxKeyLength(100);
```

This will set maximum text length of legend as 100.

Comment: This does solve my problem. But the problem is we always have to find the max length of legends values !